SQL: How to filter all the rows containing a certain product based on the value of a third column
I have a table with three columns: job_id, part, and time, which represent the ID of a shop job, the part manufactured in that job, and the time taken for that job, respectively.



Job_id
Part
Time




1
A
0


2
F
0


3
F
0


4
C
10


5
B
0


6
D
5


7
F
0


8
B
0


9
E
0


10
F
10



In this table, a higher job_id corresponds to a more recent job. For example, for Part F, job_id = 10 represents the most recent job, while job_id = 2 is the oldest.
I need to select all the rows for a part where the most recent job (i.e., the row with the highest job_id) has a 'time' of 0. For instance:
Part A: Select it because its most recent job (job_id = 1) has time = 0.
Part B: Select both rows because its most recent job (job_id = 8) has time = 0.
Part F: Do not select any rows because its most recent job (job_id = 10) does not have time = 0.
Desired result:



Job_id
Part
Time




1
A
0


8
B
0


5
B
0


9
E
0



Since we're selecting rows from different parts based on their most recent job's time, I believe I need to partition the data by part. To achieve this, I have used the ROW_NUMBER() function to assign row numbers to each group.



Job_id
Part
Time
row_number




1
A
0
1


8
B
0
1


5
B
0
2


4
C
10
1


6
D
5
1


9
E
0
1


10
F
10
1


7
F
0
2


3
F
0
3


2
F
0
4



However, I am unsure how to use this partitioned data to extract the desired result.
I am using MySQL for this task.

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1 for how to get the most recent row for each part. You can then filter this based on time=0. Finally, join this with the original table to get all the rows for that part.

@Barmar I'd prefer to add the text as well but while I can do that with the code, I'm not sure how to add tables in the text box. When I try to write it as a table, it gives me a single line of text.  My question had no code, only tables. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support for table markdown.

with 
src (job_id, part, time) AS (
   select 1,'a',0 union all
   select 2,'f',0 union all 
   select 3,'f',0 union all 
   select 4,'c',10 union all 
   select 5,'b',0 union all 
   select 6,'d',5 union all 
   select 7,'f',0 union all 
   select 8,'b',0 union all 
   select 9,'e',0 union all
   select 10,'f',10   
),
get_last (job_id, part, time, last_time) AS (
  SELECT job_id, part, time,
         FIRST_VALUE(time) OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY job_id DESC)
  FROM src
)
SELECT job_id, part, time
FROM get_last
WHERE last_time = 0
ORDER BY part, job_id




job_id
part
time




1
a
0


5
b
0


8
b
0


9
e
0



fiddle
PS. Thanks to Sergey for source script.

Please add an explanation.

@DaleK What explanation do you want to see? OP tells: I need to select all the rows for a part where the most recent job (i.e., the row with the highest job_id) has a 'time' of 0. FIRST_VALUE() gets a time for the recent job, WHERE compares it with zero. Everything is absolutely clear...

Even adding that, "You can make use of the FIRST_VALUE() function to obtain blah blah" is already an improvement. You are trying to make the answer useful to everyone, and some people struggle to understand a complex query.  Adding a clear text description makes the solution clearer.

with table_1(job_id,part,time)AS
(
   select 1,'a',0 union all
   select 2,'f',0 union all 
   select 3,'f',0 union all 
   select 4,'c',10 union all 
   select 5,'b',0 union all 
   select 6,'d',5 union all 
   select 7,'f',0 union all 
   select 8,'b',0 union all 
   select 9,'e',0 union all
   select 10,'f',10   
)

SELECT T.JOB_ID,Z.PART, T.TIME FROM
  (
     SELECT XQ.JOB_ID,XQ.PART,XQ.TIME FROM
      (
         select t.job_id,t.part,t.time,
          ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by t.part order by t.job_id desc)as xcol
         from table_1 as t
      )AS XQ 
      WHERE XQ.xcol=1 AND XQ.TIME=0
   )Z
  JOIN TABLE_1 AS T ON Z.PART=T.PART

Please try this one. I tired my best to implement the suggested solution

Please add an explanation.
